# how to throw away c runtime, but still be able to load and use shared libraries?

Tags: c, linux, runtime, shared-libraries

I was impressed by http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html and http://shaurz.wordpress.com/2008/06/02/finding-linux-gateso1-in-assembly/ , and now i want to use these to do something practical.

Comment: On a powerful system like a modern PC (or even tablet, phone, ...) there's nothing *practical* about not using the runtime.

Comment: That's nice. Do you have a question?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan look at the title

Comment: @us2012 Throwing away code i don't want is always useful.

Comment: You aren't throwing it away. You are just forcing yourself to reimplement lots of it. The runtime is still there. It will still be sitting in memory. You'll end up using more resources!

Comment: You might use smaller C runtimes. Look into [dietlibc](http://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/) and [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/). And you might link statically (but I don't recommend that).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch But now you'll have more distinct runtimes in memory and so consume more resource.

Comment: Well, the OP might have some embedded Linux running only very few executables... He might compile all of them choosing a single smaller libc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since you're going to have to do many things that require communicating with the operating system (let's assume Linux), you must do *system calls*. Since those are generally implemented by the C runtime library, you are going to have to re-implement them all.

At a minimum I would assume you need to do system calls to:

1. Query the file, to learn its size
2. Allocate the required memory
3. Map the memory into your process' address space, making sure its executable
4. Ask the kernel to load the named file into the newly allocated memory

Then it's probably more or less straight-forward application-level code to:

1. Inspect the ELF headers of the loaded data, identifying entry points
2. Applying initalizers for static data
3. Relocating any position-independent code to properly reference the mapped space

I'm almost certainly missing a bunch of things; while this isn't "magic", it's still pretty heavy lifting. You will have your work cut out for you, to say the least. Enjoy.

Comment: The first 4 steps are automatically done (by the kernel) thru the `execve` syscall (and also by `ld.so` dynamic linker, for shared objects)

Answer (score 3):

That tutorial already tells you about all the things you need to do in order to not have to link an executable against libc (namely, define appropriate entry and exit points).

From there, you can do whatever you like, it's just that you'll have to re-write even the simplest stuff like `printf` et cetera, since practically everything that *does* stuff, apart from manipulating variables, needs system calls.

Let me reiterate that you are not going to save anything by going down this route. Your shell, your init system, your desktop environment all need `libc` already, so it's loaded anyways. Read about 'shared libraries' to see why this means an extra executable with `libc` dependence doesn't waste memory. On the contrary, if you reimplement all the system calls you need, all that implementation *will* have to be loaded into RAM, where it can't be shared with anything else because everything else uses `libc`.